# Create new dict in dict and define key to exist values

Tags: list, dictionary, nested, key

How can I to create new dictionary in dictionary and define keys to exist values.
What I have:

```
{
'Salmon:': ['150.7,', 'False'], 
'Carrot:': ['30.5,', 'True']
}
```

What I need:

```
{
'Salmon': {'nutritional_value': 150.7, 'vegan': False},
'Carrot': {'nutritional_value': 30.5, 'vegan': True}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'Salmon:': ['150.7,', 'False'], 'Carrot:': ['30.5,', 'True']}

new_dict = { key:{"nutritional_val":val[0] ,"vegan":val[1] } for (key,val) in data.items()}
```

Here you can use dictionary comprehension

For every element in the `data` dictionary you could specify values as a dictionary with `nutritional_value` and `vegan` as keys and then their values from the list that would be the `val` here

It should do the thing